# How to create own templates in Texmaker?

Tags: templates, preamble

like the title already says, I´m looking for a possibility to create own document templates containing all the relevant document class, package and formatting information.
Since I´m often using the same or very similar preambles, it would be much easier to just select a template instead of typing everything or copying the preamble from an existing document everytime I want to create a new one.

Is there any possibility to do that? I am using Texmaker as editor.

Thanks a lot in advance. :)

Comment: you mean like adding a custom template to TeXmaker?

Comment: Texmaker don't have template (in usual sense) but you can go to menu: User->User tags->Edit user tags.

Answer (score 3):

If you were to switch from TeXmaker to TeXstudio, you could create your own templates.

Create and save a new `.tex`-file, enter all your needed packages, formats, etc. and then goto `File -> Make Template` to add license information.

Once this is finished, you can select your template from the menu via `File -> New from template -> User`.

Else, you could add a template by putting it inside the `config`-folder of TeXstudio: `\texstudio\templates\user`

Comment: Ok, seems like switching the GUI is the only opportunity for now to create real templates.
Since I´m already used to and very happy with the functionality of Texmaker, I´d prefer to stay with Texmaker.
I guess, I´m going to create a .tex file containing all the relevant information and use them whenever I create a new document. Like the answer in the linked question above mentions. :D

Thanks for your answers, anyway. :)